# Azure Dev Ops - Sentry integration - How does it work

Tags: azure-devops, integration, sentry

do I've tried to integrate ADO with Sentry and installaed it from  the next link

[https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Sentry.sentry&ssr=false#qna]

Still I do not see the option to start using it on even configure it on the Orgnization Settings

Do I need the ADO integration on Sentry to be installed as well?

I could not find any guidance on how to make the configuration and the one on the marketplace

does not seem any useful, thanks

I cannot configure the integration (so connect it with my Sentry account)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hi @David, you can refer to [sentry doc](https://docs.sentry.io/product/integrations/source-code-mgmt/azure-devops/) to sync information between sync and Azure DevOps.

Answer (score 0):

> Do I need the ADO integration on Sentry to be installed as well?

Yes, you need to install `Azure Devops` on sentry.
In Sentry.io, navigate to Settings > Integrations > Azure DevOps and click "Add Installation".
[image]

If you want to know how to sync information between Azure devops and Sentry,you can follow below steps to integrate ADO with Sentry. Here is an example about issue sync.

1.Please make sure you have installed Sentry from [marketplace](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Sentry.sentry&ssr=false#overview) and Azure Devops on Sentry.
For detailed installation, please refer to:

https://docs.sentry.io/product/integrations/source-code-mgmt/azure-devops/#install

2 Configure your organization settings to decide which information in Sentry (status, assignment, comments) should be synced to Azure DevOps.
Here i tested `Sync Sentry Assignment to Azure DevOps`

[image]
3.Navigated to a specific issue, you’ll find the Linked Issues section on the right hand panel. Here, you’ll be able to create or link Azure DevOps issues.
[image]

4 When an issue is assigned in Sentry, assign its linked Azure DevOps work item to the same user(DX for example).

[image]

Besides you can refer to the following doc to syn other information you want.
https://docs.sentry.io/product/integrations/source-code-mgmt/azure-devops/

Hope it can help you.